# PayPal Angular Integration

Tags: javascript, angular, paypal

I have an Angular application, where I need to integrate a PayPal payment process. I've been following some tutorials, but now I am stuck with this.

**What I've done until now?**

1. run 'npm install xcomponent'
2. run 'npm instal paypal-checkout'
3. add `<scriptsrc="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>` to index.html
4. add `<paypal-button [props]="{ payment: payment, onAuthorize: onAuthorize }"></paypal-button>` to the page I need the
   button to be rendered
5. At app.module.ts, exported and imported (in NgModule imports list) a new Module like this:

   declare const paypal:any; 
    export const PayPalButtonModule = paypal.Button.driver('angular2',{Component,NgModule,ElementRef,NgZone});
6. Add to the component (lets call it MyPayPalComponent.ts) I need to render the button:

   payment() { 
     console.log('payment'); 
   } 
   onAuthorize() {
      console.log("onAuthorize"); 
   }

And the button is being rendered, but what is the next step? How to, at MyPayPalComponent.ts, "overload" the functions payment, onAuthorize and onCancel, to make everything work?